# Printing "this" in various cases in javascript

Tags: javascript

I was asking this and it's a little bit confusing...
What will be printed on the console.

```html
var a = {
 b : {
  foo : function(){
   console.log(this);
   }
  }
 }

a.b.foo();//in console : foo function

var b = a.b;
b.foo();//in console : foo function

var foo = a.b.foo;
foo();////in console : window
```

The first one is quite obvious.
Why second print is also foo function and third is window object?
thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `foo()`, the line `console.log(this);` will log the object that the function belongs to.

You're slightly mistaken about the `console.log` result for the first two examples. The `console.log` doesn't log `foo()`, rather it's logging `a.b` -- which is the object that `foo()` belongs too. Try adding `console.log(a.b);` to your code and you'll see that it logs the same result.

In your third example, `window` is logged because `window` is the base scope of all javascript objects. It's automatically "attached" to each variable you define.

So for example:

```
window.foo = 5;
```

Is the same as:

```
var foo = 5;
```

The first two examples invoke `foo()` when it's a child of another object so `window.foo` does not exist.

Comment: This is valid in browsers, but the global object might have another name than `window`, if you are not in a browser. (For example, node.js on server -side)

Answer (score 0):

The second one use a reference to `a.b`, so you are still executing in the context of the `{ a: {b} }` object, `this` is the object.

In the third one you just get a reference to the function itself, attached to a global variable, so no sub-object context when calle. Only the global  context (which is `window`in a browser console, but not same result for other javascript context, like node.js)